# Text field in label in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

In header tab the asterisk symbol will be visible if they make any changes in that tab. Now i want to make the asterisk size large.

I am trying to make text of label to large.could anyone help me out with this.

```
 <HeaderTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="CommunicationsTabHeader" runat="server" Text="Communications"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="CommunicationNotification" Visible="false" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
    Style="color: Red;" **Text="*">**</asp:Label>
 </HeaderTemplate>
```